# Android System Module Reads Zero Bytes

Tags: crashes, cache, application-manager

My Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 started wigging out on me. While I was desperately tapping a Retreat, I think I may have deleted or disabled something. Apps crash frequently since and the "Android System" module in Settings/Application Manager shows zero bytes in all categories - cache, data, app, total, etc.  However,  it is not turned off.
How to correct this?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and include/link a screenshot (where it says "zero bytes")? Thanks!